# Can I change the size of a sprite in XCode? (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit and I want to know if there is a way of scaling down the size of a Sprite inside XCode without changing the resolution of the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An SKSpriteNode has the property `size` which you can specify. If you want to scale a sprite, however, the easiest way would be to use the method `setScale`. It takes a parameter of type float and it scales the image by the specified degree. For example, if you had a sprite:

```
var mySprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"myImage.png")
```

you could then scale the sprite to be twice its original size:

```
mySprite.setScale(2)
```

Comment: That gives me an error with `Declaration Expected` and chaining `setScale` also causes an error....